# regexp to modify matches with replace pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

The string:

```
'some text [2string] some another [test] and [test-]'.match(/\[\D+?\]+/g);
```

How to modify regexp i've written to match also [2string] (string with integer), and replace all the matches with quoted values between [], so they become ['2string']

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var txt = 'some text [2string] some another [test] and [test-]';
var spl = txt.split('[').join("['").split(']').join("']");
console.log(spl);
```

or use simple String.replace().

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cdAve/)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
'some text [2string] some another [test] and [test-]'.replace(/\[(.*?)\]/g, "['$1']");
```